# how to update my app informations in appStore connection?

Tags: xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

I'm trying to send my to appStore but I've just run into an issue, I want this app to be available just on iPhones and not iPads but appStore Connection keep asking me iPad Screenshots before I send the app for revision, on XCode I've changed the deployment information...[image]

but I couldn't find an update button to send this new information to appStore Connection, Should I restart the whole process again?

thank you in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

1. If your app if already live in the AppStore you cannot change this.
2. If you have already uploaded your app to AppStoreConnect but NOT submitted it, simply just change the bundle ID. Then make a new app in App Store Connect and copy over info.